# create and retrieve bookmarks using box api?

Tags: box-api

Is there a way to create and retrieve bookmarks using the box api 2.0?  I have found shared links and files but not actually bookmarks.  Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place.  Any help would be appreciated.
--Update--
I have found this functionality under the V1 API (which will go offline come December):
http://developers.box.net/w/page/12923957/Bookmarks
Please advise.  Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a question for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is not – this is a minimally used feature. so we won't be building support for it for a while, if at all.